# INSERT into a table using data from 2 other tables

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Okay so I have 3 tables; enduserdevicemap,enduser, and device.

I'm inserting into enduserdevicemap but I need information from both the enduser table and the device table.

```
insert into enduserdevicemap (fkenduser,fkdevice,defaultprofile,tkuserassociation) 
select enduser.pkid,device.pkid from enduser,device 
where enduser.userid = 1001, device.name like '%6%' 
values (enduser.pkid,device.pkid,'f','1')
```

I need to get device.pkid and enduser.pkid however I keep getting syntax error. I know this is wrong in so many ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the number of attributes to INSERT should be matching with the number of attributes of SELECT.

Second, you don't need the last `values` line

Third, are you sure you are not missing a relation between the tables: enduser and device, because this will insert all possibilities.

Example, (it might not make sense for the choice of attributes but this is just an example of how to use insert from another table):

```
INSERT INTO enduserdevicemap (fkenduser,fkdevice,defaultprofile,tkuserassociation) 
SELECT e.fkenduser,e.fkdevice,d.defaultprofile,d.tkuserassociation
FROM enduser e,device d 
WHERE enduser.userid = 1001 AND device.name like '%6%'
```

Comment: The defaultprofile and userassociation don't really have to be added I guess. I'm gonna try this now.

Comment: I used 
INSERT INTO enduserdevicemap (fkenduser,fkdevice) SELECT enduser.fkenduser,device.fkdevice FROM enduser,device WHERE enduser.userid = 1001, device.name like '%6%'
and it gave me a syntax error.

Comment: In the where condition, you should write: WHERE enduser.userid = 1001 AND device.name like '%6%'

Answer (score 0):

you can not have both select and values. it is either one or the other.
I would do the following
insert into enduserdevicemap (fkenduser,fkdevice,defaultprofile,tkuserassociation) 
select enduser.pkid,device.pkid, 'f', '1' from enduser,device 
where enduser.userid = 1001, device.name like '%6%'

not also that the 2 tables in the select are not joined,
resulting in a cartesian.